# Using Drupal 7 VBO and Rules Component Action Set to unblock users - insufficient permissions

Tags: permissions, drupal-7, drupal-views

When users join up to the site I'm creating, their accounts are Blocked.

I want to make it possible for a user with a special role (user admin) to approve those new users, but I don't want to grant global permissions to that user which might affect other users and user data.

I've created a View with a VBO on it that accesses a Rules Component Action Set which simply unblocks the user(s) it is passed. However, running this action results in a message of:

*Skipped Activate user on user New User due to insufficient permissions.*

In order to get the action to run successfully I have had to grant the user admin role the **Administer users** permission. Once I do that, though, my user admin is able to mess around with far more than I want them to be able to (including blocking users and changing user data).

I have tried to use the Actions permissions module to provide the permission for this action, but as a Rules component it isn't listed (the readme indicates there is an open feature request to add this functionality, *but looking at it, it has been implemented in Rules, and appears to give me the ability to limit use of a component, which I've done, but not permit the changes in the action to be made if the user doesn't have the permission to carry out those actions - ie. I want a form of sudo, if you will*).

What options, if any, do I have?